# How do I call Methods expecting unknown primitives when I have Strings?

Tags: java, reflection

I have some XML data (meaning it's all Strings) that I need to add to fields on an object. The object has fields and methods that correspond to the XML data. For instance, `<RmkSk>123</RmkSk>` in the XML corresponds with the method `setRmkSk(String)`. However, occasionally I have a field that expects another type, such as int, long, or double. `<Capacity>456</Capacity>`, for instance, corresponds with the method `setCapacity(double)`. I can use reflection to see the parameter types but I don't know how to reliably convert the strings to the appropriate data type.

```
for(Method m: o.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if(!m.getName().startsWith("set")) continue;
    System.out.println(m.getName());
    for(Class c: m.getParameterTypes()) {
        System.out.println("  " + c.getName());
    }
}
```

Displays, for instance:

```
setEqpSk
  java.lang.String
setCapacity
  double
```

If it were `java.lang.Double` it would be easy (relatively) to use reflection again to call `Double.valueof` but it's the primitive type, not the Object type. Is there a reliable way to set this other than uppercasing the first letter and concatenating it with `"java.lang."`? Am I going about this the wrong way?

And before anyone suggests an external library, while I'm open to hearing about them, this is on a restricted government system and it's not always easy to get things like that approved.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm trying to avoid the following:

```
if (types[0] == String.class) {
    m.invoke(o, value);
} else if (types[0] == double.class || types[0] == Double.class) {
    m.invoke(o, Double.parseDouble(value));
} else if (types[0] == int.class || types[0] == Integer.class) {
    m.invoke(o, Integer.parseInt(value));
} else if (types[0] == //add checks for EVERY primitive type
```

etc etc.

Comment: Can you modify the XML data?  If you can, you could add the expected data type.  Otherwise you would need to make two attempts to set the data, first using `Double` and then using `double`...

Comment: It's currently a String, "456". I'm retrieving the data from XML supplied by someone else.

Comment: If the parameter type is `double` then you should know you're dealing with a primitive and should be able to convert accordingly, if it was `java.lang.Double`, you would need to create a new `Double` object

Comment: The problem is, how do I convert a String to an *arbitrary* primitive type? I'm able to discover that the method wants a double. How do I reliably call Double.valueof? There is no double.valueof or I'd call that. I need to be able to do this for long as well (and possibly short, int, byte, and boolean).

Comment: `Double.parseDouble`....?

Comment: What's wrong with `Double.valueOf`?  The javadoc for `Method#invoke` says that "Individual parameters are automatically unwrapped to match primitive formal parameters", so if you're going to call the method via reflection (`method.invoke()`) and it takes a `double`, you'll need to create a `Double` anyway.  Perhaps I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @ajb Nothing is wrong with `Double.valueof`. But when the method is expecting `double` how do I go from there to `java.lang.Double.valueof` reliably?

Comment: If `cl` is the parameter's class, then something like `Object param; if (cl == double.class) param = Double.valueOf(s); else if (cl == int.class) param = Integer.valueOf(s); else...`  I don't think there's a shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, with autoboxing, you can get away with using `Double` for methods that expect `double`, for example...

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test101 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>(3);
        values.put("EqpSk", "123");
        values.put("Capacity", "456");
        values.put("Quanity", "987");

        Test101 o = new Test101();
        for (Method m : o.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            String name = m.getName();
            if (name.startsWith("set")) {
                name = name.substring(3);
                if (values.containsKey(name)) {
                    try {
                        String value = values.get(name);
                        Class<?>[] types = m.getParameterTypes();
                        if (types[0] == String.class) {
                            m.invoke(o, value);
                        } else if (types[0] == double.class || types[0] == Double.class) {
                            m.invoke(o, Double.parseDouble(value));
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setEqpSk(String value) {
        System.out.println("EqpSk = " + value);
    }

    public void setCapacity(double value) {
        System.out.println("Capacity = " + value);
    }

    public void setQuanity(Double value) {
        System.out.println("Quanity = " + value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you saying it's best to explicitly list each of the primitives I might run into instead of trying to get the class and methods through reflection? Referring to your if/else if

Comment: All I did was determined the class type of the parameter and ensured that value I passed to the method was the correct class type. You might have an issue if you have two methods with the same name where one takes the primitive type and one takes the object type, but that's a use case you'll need to solve for as you don't really have enough information at hand.

Comment: I understand exactly what you did. My problem is I'm going to end up with like 5 else ifs because I need to check for all of the primitive types. I was hoping I could do some magic where I get the parameter type and call valueof on that class to save myself some typing and make the code look cleaner.

Comment: And, yes, I to wish there was

Comment: @Derek Extracting the `if .. else if .. else if` into its own method that returns an `Object` would be fairly clean.  Probably the best you can do.  I can think of some ways to set up a map that could convert `primitive.class` to `BoxedType.class` and then use reflection to find the `valueOf` method for the `BoxedType`.  But that's too heavyweight when there's only a handful of primitives.